# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.CCParser$CCLineBuilder.setCharAt

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview, imasdk

Hi in my application i am playing m3u8 video url using videoview(Sample player of IMA SDK). Sometime i am getting this exception after switch ON closedcaption option from device setting. I did not understand what the thing i am doing wrong. And How to resolved this issue.
Please suggest how to resolve this issue.
*device info Android 6.0 and device MOTOG3.*

```
 08-04 14:29:32.118: W/System.err(1445): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.CCParser$CCLineBuilder.setCharAt(int, char)' on a null object reference
08-04 14:29:32.118: W/System.err(1445):     at android.media.CCParser$CCMemory.der(ClosedCaptionRenderer.java:613)
08-04 14:29:32.119: W/System.err(1445):     at android.media.CCParser.handleCtrlCode(ClosedCaptionRenderer.java:280)
08-04 14:29:32.119: W/System.err(1445):     at android.media.CCParser.parse(ClosedCaptionRenderer.java:175)
08-04 14:29:32.119: W/System.err(1445):     at android.media.ClosedCaptionTrack.onData(ClosedCaptionRenderer.java:93)
08-04 14:29:32.119: W/System.err(1445):     at android.media.SubtitleTrack.onData(SubtitleTrack.java:81)
08-04 14:29:32.119: W/System.err(1445):     at android.media.MediaPlayer$1.onSubtitleData(MediaPlayer.java:2192)
08-04 14:29:32.119: W/System.err(1445):     at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:2949)
08-04 14:29:32.119: W/System.err(1445):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-04 14:29:32.119: W/System.err(1445):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
08-04 14:29:32.119: W/System.err(1445):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
08-04 14:29:32.119: W/System.err(1445):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-04 14:29:32.119: W/System.err(1445):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
08-04 14:29:32.119: W/System.err(1445):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please suggest in respect of my question. i am unable to find why i am getting only when closed caption is on.

Comment: How we should do it without code?

Comment: Sir i am using IMA SDK sample player code from https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/android/download

Comment: This is the tutorial which i am using https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/android/quickstart